# Default @ContextConfiguration working but not when manually set

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

I have an Application Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

And I am running a test as

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class CollectiveOneWebappApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void testDecisionAlgorithm() throws IOException {
    ...
    }
```

It works fine. Now I want to change the configuartion class for the test, so I created

```
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

And updated the test to

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class CollectiveOneWebappApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void testDecisionAlgorithm() throws IOException {
    ...
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Its unable to find the bean of Hibernate entity factory

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]
```

I tought for a moment, that using

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class CollectiveOneWebappApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void testDecisionAlgorithm() throws IOException {
    ...
    }
```

would bring me back to the default behavior, but it doesn't. Any idea on why `@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)` is different from no annotation at all?

Comment: Did you also annotate the `TestConfig` class with `@Configuration` also? It must have it. I would also recommend you to use `@Profile`(s).

Comment: tried with and without that annotation. Should it be there?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@ContextConfiguration` you should:

- annotate your test config with `@TestConfiguration`
- mark your `sessionFactory()` method additionally with `@Primary` to make sure that test bean is selected over the one from production configuration.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I have annotated the `TestConfig.class` with `@TestConfiguration` but the `AppConfig.class` is still being used at context loading...

Comment: @JoseOspina `@Primary` is also needed in case you have several candidate beans. The `AppConfig` may be loaded because you haven't indicated the component scan path, but it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @grape_mao I have added the `@Primary` annotation as well. Besides calling `AppConfig` to create the `sessionFactory()` bean, context loading also let the scheduled methods enabled due to the `@EnableScheduling` annotation, which is what I want to disabled during tests.

Comment: @JoseOspina have a look at [ComponentScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html). It is used on `TestConfig` class.

Comment: just did, don't know what to do with it though. Its a bit frustrating :(. I just want Spring to use a different config class instead of `AppConfig`, that's all. I will comment the `@EnableScheduling` for a while, I really need to run the test today...

Comment: If you don't want your AppConfig to be picked you should not use `@SpringBootTest` annotation. Just go with `@ContextConfiguration`.